# Is it possible to develop Windows 8 app using Visual Studio Express Windows Phone?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, windows-store-apps

Is it possible to develop Windows 8 app using Visual Studio Express Windows Phone? The questions might look very silly, but I am very new to Windows app development. So please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here you go, straight from the horses mouth.](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) So yes!

[Here is what you want, you can target both wp8.1and w8.1.](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-8)

I remember you used to get the express alongside the w7.x sdk, terrible annoying if you were already sitting on pro or ultimate ;)

Hope it helps! (I would rather not install the expres on my computer as I already have ultimate installed, so I only trust what the article there says.)

Cheers,

Stian

Comment: @Juno no problem", there are things happening on this front. [You also may want to check out this, universal apps](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/building-universal-Windows-apps). I've started smelling on [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/?_bt=44014802708&_bk=xamarin&_bm=e&gclid=COXygo2uwsACFcoMcwodWkYAZA) which allows you to target android, iphone and wp8.1 in one vs solution, a bit offtopic, but some heads up :)